# Parsing data from byte array

Tags: vb.net

I'm writing a small program to retrieve data from a Counter-Strike 2 gameserver like map name, number of players, server version, etc... using the source A2S_Info protocol.

This is my code:

```
Private A2S_INFO_Request() As Byte = {&HFF, &HFF, &HFF, &HFF, &H54, &H53, &H6F, &H75, &H72, &H63, &H65, &H20, &H45, &H6E, &H67, &H69, &H6E, &H65, &H20, &H51, &H75, &H65, &H72, &H79, &H0}
Dim targetServer As New IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(HostName.Text), Port.Value)

Using client As New UdpClient
    client.Client.ReceiveTimeout = 5000
    client.Client.SendTimeout = 5000

    client.Send(A2S_INFO_Request, A2S_INFO_Request.Length, targetServer)
    Dim Challenge_Request As Byte() = client.Receive(targetServer)
    Dim Challenge_Bytes As Byte() = {Challenge_Request(5), Challenge_Request(6), Challenge_Request(7), Challenge_Request(8)}
    Dim A2S_Request_With_Challenge_Bytes As Byte() = {&HFF, &HFF, &HFF, &HFF, &H54, &H53, &H6F, &H75, &H72, &H63, &H65, &H20, &H45, &H6E, &H67, &H69, &H6E, &H65, &H20, &H51, &H75, &H65, &H72, &H79, &H0, Challenge_Bytes(0), Challenge_Bytes(1), Challenge_Bytes(2), Challenge_Bytes(3)}
    client.Send(A2S_Request_With_Challenge_Bytes, A2S_Request_With_Challenge_Bytes.Length, targetServer)
    Dim A2S_Info As Byte() = client.Receive(targetServer)

    RichTextBox1.AppendText(vbCrLf & "Response: " & System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(A2S_Info) & vbCrLf)
End Using
```

This is the server response (Byte array):

[image: View application image]

```
    I★ [ESP/EU] | BLACKBØX | DUST2-ONLY | 16K$ | 4 GRENADESde_dust2csgoCounter-Strike 2 @dw1.39.8.3 ?u # 0empty,16k,CS2,Dust2,casual,españa,only,spain,secure
```

I'm looking a propper way to parse the data this way:

**Server name:** [ESP/EU] | BLACKBØX | DUST2-ONLY | 16K$ | 4 GRENADES
**Map:** de_dust2
**Server version:** 1.39.8.3

Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: There's a project to do it more thoroughly than my answer provides for on GitHub at [QueryMaster](https://github.com/armageddonapps/QueryMaster).

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [documentation on Valve](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Server_queries) you can figure out how to extract the data items.

Using some example data on that page in a .NET 8 VB.NET Console app...

```
Imports System.Text

Module Program
    Sub Main(args As String())

        ' Valve response documentation: https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Server_queries
        Dim respHex = "FFFFFFFF490267616D653278732E636F6D20436F756E7465722D537472696B6520536F757263652023310064655F647573740063737472696B6500436F756E7465722D537472696B653A20536F7572636500F000051004646C0000312E302E302E323200"
        Dim respBytes = Convert.FromHexString(respHex)

        Dim offset = 6 'skip FF FF FF FF (header byte) (protocol byte)

        Dim serverNameBB = respBytes.Skip(offset).TakeWhile(Function(a) a <> 0).ToArray()
        offset += serverNameBB.Count + 1

        Dim mapNameBB = respBytes.Skip(offset).TakeWhile(Function(a) a <> 0).ToArray()
        offset += mapNameBB.Count + 1

        Dim folderNameBB = respBytes.Skip(offset).TakeWhile(Function(a) a <> 0).ToArray()
        offset += folderNameBB.Count + 1

        Dim gameNameBB = respBytes.Skip(offset).TakeWhile(Function(a) a <> 0).ToArray()
        offset += gameNameBB.Count + 1

        Dim serverName = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(serverNameBB)
        Dim mapName = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(mapNameBB)
        Dim folderName = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(folderNameBB)
        Dim gameName = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(gameNameBB)

        Console.WriteLine(serverName)
        Console.WriteLine(mapName)
        Console.WriteLine(folderName)
        Console.WriteLine(gameName)

        Console.ReadLine()

    End Sub
End Module
```

Outputs:

```
game2xs.com Counter-Strike Source #1
de_dust
cstrike
Counter-Strike: Source
```

There may be off-by-one errors. I am not sure that it uses UTF-8 as opposed to Unicode (=UTF-16), but I just used what was shown in the question.

It was not clear to me, from the documentation, how to get the server version.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Finally i've managed to make it work and published the source code in GitHub: https://github.com/fpaezf/vb.net-a2s_Info

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Thank you for the info. Not much experience posting on StackOverflow. I'm building a source game server admin tool like HLWS so i need a minimal/functional code to start from. Here's the tool: https://github.com/fpaezf/CS2-RCON-Tool-V2

Comment: @fpaezf Microsoft appear to be *pretending* that they haven't abandoned VB.NET, so maybe you'd be better off going in the C# direction. IMHO. (C# next: here's a load of new features... VB.NET: we said we were "feature-complete" in 2017?.)

Comment: I started with vb6 long ago when i was 13, now i'm 40. Managed to migrate to vb.net and currently is my main language. I've built some projects in C# but vb.net is easier and faster for me since I have more knowledge. I am just an amateur programmer and I have no training beyond what I have learned these years on my own. Happy new year!.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim targetServer As New IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(HostName.Text), Port.Value)
    Using client As New UdpClient
        client.Client.ReceiveTimeout = 5000
        client.Client.SendTimeout = 5000

        client.Send(A2S_INFO_Request, A2S_INFO_Request.Length, targetServer)
        Dim Challenge_Request As Byte() = client.Receive(targetServer)
        Dim Challenge_Bytes As Byte() = {Challenge_Request(5), Challenge_Request(6), Challenge_Request(7), Challenge_Request(8)}
        Dim A2S_Request_With_Challenge_Bytes As Byte() = {&HFF, &HFF, &HFF, &HFF, &H54, &H53, &H6F, &H75, &H72, &H63, &H65, &H20, &H45, &H6E, &H67, &H69, &H6E, &H65, &H20, &H51, &H75, &H65, &H72, &H79, &H0, Challenge_Bytes(0), Challenge_Bytes(1), Challenge_Bytes(2), Challenge_Bytes(3)}
        client.Send(A2S_Request_With_Challenge_Bytes, A2S_Request_With_Challenge_Bytes.Length, targetServer)
        Dim A2S_Info As Byte() = client.Receive(targetServer)

        Dim stream As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream(A2S_Info)
        Dim reader As BinaryReader = New BinaryReader(stream)


        Dim header As Integer = reader.ReadInt32()
        'MsgBox(header.ToString)
        Dim protocol As String = reader.ReadByte()
        'MsgBox(protocol)
        Dim ver As String = reader.ReadByte()
        'MsgBox(ver)
        Dim serverName As String = ReadSteamString(reader)
        ' MsgBox(serverName)
        Dim mapName As String = ReadSteamString(reader)
        'MsgBox(mapName)
        Dim folder As String = ReadSteamString(reader)
        'MsgBox(folder)
        Dim Game As String = ReadSteamString(reader)
        ' MsgBox(Game)
        Dim SteamApplicationID As Short = reader.ReadInt16()
        'MsgBox(SteamApplicationID.ToString)
        Dim players As String = reader.ReadByte()
        'MsgBox(players)
        Dim maxplayers As String = reader.ReadByte()
        'MsgBox(maxplayers)
        Dim bots As String = reader.ReadByte()
        'MsgBox(bots)

        Dim ServerType As Byte = reader.ReadByte()
        Dim dOut As Char = Convert.ToChar(ServerType)
        'MsgBox(dOut) '100 = dedicated

        Dim ServerOS As Byte = reader.ReadByte()
        Dim vOut As Char = Convert.ToChar(ServerOS)
        'MsgBox(vOut)

        Dim Visibility As String = reader.ReadByte() ' 0 = public - 1 = private
        'MsgBox(Visibility)

        Dim VAC As String = reader.ReadByte() ' 0 = Disabled - 1 = Enabled
        'MsgBox(VAC)

        Dim Version As String = ReadSteamString(reader)
        'MsgBox(Version)

        For i As Integer = 0 To A2S_Info.Length - 1
            If A2S_Info(i) = 0 Then
                A2S_Info(i) = 23
            End If
        Next

        RichTextBox1.AppendText(vbCrLf & "Response: " & System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(A2S_Info) & vbCrLf)
    End Using
End Sub

Private Function ReadSteamString(ByVal reader As BinaryReader) As String
    Dim str As List(Of Byte) = New List(Of Byte)()
    Dim nextByte As Byte = reader.ReadByte()

    While nextByte <> 0
        str.Add(nextByte)
        nextByte = reader.ReadByte()
    End While

    Return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(str.ToArray())
End Function
```

Comment: Can you make your code work with `Option Strict On`?